# Integration indefinite integral of multiple functions

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need help integrating

$$\frac{x}{1-\exp(-x^2/a^2)}\exp((x-u)^2/2s^2)$$

wrt $x$, where $a$ and $u$ are constants

Comment: Any bounds of integration or just the indefinite integral?

Comment: Are you sure of the integrand ?

Comment: This does not seem to have a closed form solution.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, re-edited the mathjax, OP was missing some parenthesis, waiting for edit to be accepted

Comment: @George Audu, please make sure the formula is indeed what you are asking

Comment: Is the integrand supposed to read $\frac{x}{1-e^{-(x/a)^2}}\exp{\left(\frac12\left(\frac{x-u}{s}\right)^2\right)}$?